# In Rails 3.1, why does my custom validator raise 'NameError: uninitialized constant' when another model is called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

In a Rails 3.1 project, I have a model class with a custom validator:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :road_must_exist_nearby, :on => :create

  # ...

  def not_a_validator_method
    Road.exists_nearby?
  end

  def road_must_exist_nearby
    if !Road.exists_nearby?
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

When I attempt to save my instance of Car ...

```
> car = Car.new
> car.save
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Car::Road
```

---

Why does calling `Road.exists_nearby?` from a normal instance method work?:

```
> car.not_a_validator_method
=> true
```

And why does calling it from a validator method raise an error, as though Rails believes `Road` should be called through `Car`?:

```
> car.road_must_exist_nearby
NameError: uninitialized constant Car::Road
```

And how can I make the validator method work?

Comment: try to restart/reload your server if the model is new.

Comment: try: `if !(::Road.exists_nearby?)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm only guessing, but I'd say it's a namespace/scope issue. Rails is interpreting the "Road" constant as existing in the scope of Car (ie Car::Road). You can probably get around it by referencing the global namespace using: "::Road"